# How to find the MAMP's MySQL location?

Tags: mamp

How to find the MAMP's MySQL location?

```
MAMP Version 4.1.1 (492)
```

On my MAMP, I started the Nginx Server and MySQL Server.

[image]

and in the Preferences, I can see MySQL's active version.

[image]

But how can I get its location? I want to create a database in this MySQL, and configure its configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways for find it:

Method 1: from the [Document](https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215197346--Where-is-my-MySQL-database-data-located-)

`MAMP 4 stores data in  /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56`

Method 2:
you can use the `ps` command to find it.

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysql
  501  2061     1   0 11:48上午 ??         0:00.06 /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log
  501  2406  2061   0 11:48上午 ??         0:00.53 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --datadir=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56 --plugin-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/plugin --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --port=8889
  501  3596   461   0 12:10下午 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql
```